# Как изменить текст через Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript

Вот сайт: https://buyskins.ru/profile
При нажатии на [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мы видим это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что бы скрипт заменял +79259005712 на +380999096499

Я составил такой скрипт:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://buyskins.ru/profile
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('+79259005712', '+380960725255');
```

Проблема в том, что когда активирован этот скрипт, на сайте не нажимаються никакие кнопки. Как это пофиксить?

Вот весь код элемента. Сделайте пожалуйста скрипт чтобы +79259005712 менялось на +380999096499

```html
<div class="sweet-alert showSweetAlert visible" data-custom-class="" data-has-cancel-button="false" data-has-confirm-button="true" data-allow-outside-click="false" data-has-done-function="false" data-animation="pop" data-timer="null" style="display: block; margin-top: -242px;">
   <div class="sa-icon sa-error" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-x-mark">
      <span class="sa-line sa-left"></span>
      <span class="sa-line sa-right"></span>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="sa-icon sa-warning" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-body"></span>
      <span class="sa-dot"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="sa-icon sa-info" style="display: none;"></div>
   <div class="sa-icon sa-success animate" style="display: block;">
      <span class="sa-line sa-tip animateSuccessTip"></span>
      <span class="sa-line sa-long animateSuccessLong"></span>
      <div class="sa-placeholder"></div>
      <div class="sa-fix"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="sa-icon sa-custom" style="display: none;"></div>
   <h2>Запрос создан</h2>
   <p style="display: block;">
   <div style="text-align:left">
      Переведите ЛЮБУЮ сумму В РУБЛЯХ (в другой валюте платеж не зачислится) на наш кошелек <b>+79259005712</b> c ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ указанием этого комментария:<br><br><b>218725</b><br>
      <hr>
      Деньги придут в течение 2-х минут (Возможно и дольше - до 20 минут).
   </div>
   </p>
   <fieldset>
      <input type="text" tabindex="3" placeholder="">
      <div class="sa-input-error"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="sa-error-container">
      <div class="icon">!</div>
      <p>Not valid!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="sa-button-container">
      <button class="cancel" tabindex="2" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
      <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
         <button class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(140, 212, 245); box-shadow: rgba(140, 212, 245, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">OK</button>
         <div class="la-ball-fall">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Найдите конкретно элемент, в котором находится текст и эту же операцию проводите с ним а нес со всем DOM.

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста. В моем первом сообщении предоставил полный код

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. `HTML` невалидный, тут не за что ухватиться. Пришлось перебрать все `<b>` и тут, что с номером заменить на свой текст.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  //этот кусок вставить в tampermonkey
  document.querySelectorAll("b").forEach(item => {
    if (item.innerHTML === "+79259005712") {
      item.innerHTML = "Любой твой текст";
    }
  });
  //до этого момента
});
```

```html
<button>НАЖМИ</button>


<p style="display:block;">
  <div style="text-align:left">
    Переведите ЛЮБУЮ сумму В РУБЛЯХ (в другой валюте платеж не зачислится) на наш кошелек <b>+79259005712</b> c ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ указанием этого комментария:<br><br><b>218725</b><br>
    <hr> Деньги придут в течение 2-х минут (Возможно и дольше - до 20 минут).
  </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Если не сложно, можете скинуть Tampermonkey script целиком?

Comment: @Alexei Нет, я не залогинен и не знаю как ведет себя сайт. Я уже и без того ответил как это сделать. В своем коде вы привели всего одну строчку кода. Это мне ничего не говорит о поведении сайта.

Comment: дополнил код ниже

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="sweet-alert showSweetAlert visible" data-custom-class="" data-has-cancel-button="true" data-has-confirm-button="true" data-allow-outside-click="false" data-has-done-function="true" data-animation="pop" data-timer="null" style="display: block; margin-top: -195px;"><div class="sa-icon sa-error" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-x-mark">
        <span class="sa-line sa-left"></span>
        <span class="sa-line sa-right"></span>
      </span>
    </div><div class="sa-icon sa-warning" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-body"></span>
      <span class="sa-dot"></span>
    </div><div class="sa-icon sa-info" style="display: none;"></div><div class="sa-icon sa-success" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-line sa-tip"></span>
      <span class="sa-line sa-long"></span>

      <div class="sa-placeholder"></div>
      <div class="sa-fix"></div>
    </div><div class="sa-icon sa-custom" style="display: none;"></div><h2>Пополнить баланс</h2>
    <p style="display: block;"><p>Пополняя счет на нашем сайте вы автоматически подтверждаете, что вы ознакомлены с правилами, а также согласны с <a style="color:white" href="/support">условиями пользования нашим сайтом</a>.</p><div style="display:block;max-width:200px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn--orange btn--3d swalClose">Отмена</div><p style="padding-top:20px;">Выберите платежную систему</p></p>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" tabindex="3" placeholder="">
      <div class="sa-input-error"></div>
    </fieldset><div class="sa-error-container">
      <div class="icon">!</div>
      <p>Not valid!</p>
    </div><div class="sa-button-container">
      <button class="cancel" tabindex="2" style="display: inline-block; box-shadow: none;">Unitpay</button>
      <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
        <button class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(140, 212, 245); box-shadow: rgba(140, 212, 245, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">Qiwi</button><div class="la-ball-fall">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></div>
```

Это код кнопки. Нужно что бы замена происходила когда **data-has-cancel-button="false"** Как так сделать?